# Very high 'Waiting (TTFB)' time - Opencart 3.0.2.0

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart-3

I've got an OpenCart website (https://www.haarhuis.shop) which took about 60 seconds to completely load any page of both the customer and admin section. I've managed to bring this down to about 15-20 seconds by increasing the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` file, cleaning up the template files and creating indexes in the MySQL database tables, but 15-20 seconds is still way too much waiting time.

I've used several dev tools to find out what the problem can be but I can't find the solution. 90% of the loading time consists of 'Waiting (TTFB)' time. See the table below:

```
Event           When        Time        Sum
Redirect        0           0           0
DNS             18          0           0
Connect         18          20          20
TTFB            38          18119       18139
Response        18156       520         18659
DOM             18321       542         19201
Interactive     18793       0           -
Content         18793       36          -
```

The server has 3 CPU's and 6GB of memory, which should be more than enough. There's a constant usage of about 8% of the memory, and when someone loads the page this will go up to about 40%. The `memory_limit` is set to 6G, so the problem doesn't lay with the server.

I've debugged the OpenCart source (starting in index.php) and most time (~10 seconds) comes from the last line, `start('catalog');`(or `start('admin');` in the admin directory). The other 5 seconds come from

```php
// VirtualQMOD
require_once('./vqmod/vqmod.php');
VQMod::bootup();
```

Further debugging shows that the `startup/router` takes the most time in `system/engine/router.php`. Now my debugging knowledge stops over here, so is there anyone who can help me out making the website faster?

Comment: Did you check redirects? Also are you using some kind of server-side caching solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you haven't created the correct database indices as described here:
https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/opencart-1-5-site-search-very-slow/

Or could it be the bug with the file /vqmod/checked.cache.php getting too big as described here:
https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=165423

(There are solutions for each issue at the links.)

Comment: So the issue described in the first link is about OpenCart 1.5 and that issue had been fixed in a later version of OpenCart already (also I already tried that with no luck). The second link however contained a post with the solution: 'To reset vqmod, delete checked.cache, mods.cache and contents of folder vqcache and logs.' I tried this and all of a sudden the website only takes less than a second to load (admin section still takes 2-3s but that's not an issue), so thank you very much, my issue is solved!